# backing up and restore drivers

Tags: wireless, drivers, backup, restore

i use a old dell inspiron ubuntu doesn't come with my wireless driver by default it does recognize the ethernet connection and used to downland wireless driver using cable connection . 
but now i dont have access to lan and im planning to reinstall i need a way to back up my drivers and install them offline after setup  how can i do it ?

this is my wireless model i used lspci command to find our abut it

0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Comment: Keep the download, and just install it then i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and run:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Is the driver shown as b43-pci-bridge? If so, you only need backup the firmware. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo nautilus /lib/firmware
```

Find the folder *b43*; right-click it and select *copy*. Now insert a USB key or similar and right-click the window that opens and select *paste*.

After you have reinstalled, insert the USB key containing the firmware file and drag and drop the b43 folder to the desktop. Now back to the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp ~/Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Thanks the back up part worked . I will tell abut the rest after reinstalling